# MYSQL Query-Building Form With Queries-multiple tables and summing up

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a report that echo's out categories and then the `total sales` for each category.

The database is split across 4 tables:

**1)** category table (holds category name and id)
**2)** products (select the `products` from here by `category id`)
**3)** sales (holds `sale id`s relating to sale items) 
**4)** sale items (holds all `sale items` and`sold amounts`)

I need to get the products I believe by the `category id`, then get the sales by `date`, then select from the `sale items` by `sale id` (only by the date) and by `product id` (so they are only by the corresponding category).

Here is my attempt.. but not working and I'm not sure I'm even on the right path, any help would be appreciated :) Thank you!

```
//Select The Category Table
$query="SELECT * FROM categories";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo $row['name']." ";

   //store category id in a string
   $cID = $row['id']."";

   //get the product id's
   $productquery = "SELECT id FROM products WHERE category_id = $cID";
   $productresult = mysql_query($productquery);
   $numproducts = mysql_num_rows($productresult);
   $productrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($productresult);
   $productid = $productrow['id']."";
 //  echo $productid;


   //get sale id from table to use to get sale items
   $salesquery = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-01 00:00:00'";
   $salesresult = mysql_query($salesquery);
   $salesnumber = mysql_num_rows($salesresult);
   $salesrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($salesresult);
   $salesid = $salesrow['id']."";
  // echo $salesid;

  //put it all together and try to sum up the subtotal col where only the category product will be tallied
  $saleitemsquery = "SELECT SUM(subtotal) FROM sales_items WHERE sale_id = $salesid AND product_id = $productid";
  $totalresult = mysql_query($saleitemsquery);
 // $totalrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($totalresult);
 echo $totalresult;

   ?>
   <br /> <br />

   <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is not 100% accurate but hopefully it is enough to get you on the right track.

```
select c.name as Name, sum(i.subtotal) as Total
from sale_items i
       inner join sales s on s.id = i.sale_id
       inner join products p on p.id = i.product_id
       inner join categories c on c.id = p.category_id
where s.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-01 00:00:00'
group by c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you've to use `JOIN`. But before you can use it you've to make sure that your tables are joining together somehow.

For example (table columns)
- table categories: **cat_id**, ..
- table sales: sale_id, **cat_id**, ..
In this case it will be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories as c
JOIN sales as s
ON c.cat_id=s.cat_id
```

For counting the occurrences use `COUNT(table.column_to_count)` after the word `SELECT`.